# 10-BFI test score compiling

Tags: measurement, personality, methodology, experimental-psychology, big-five

I am a physicist and I am doing a survey about musical genre preferences and correlation with a field of study.

I want to interpret the results from this test

[image: 10-BFI test]

I don't know how to interpret the legend, and whether there are some particular details to be taken into account:

[image: 10-BFI Score]

Thank you to all.

Reference
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jrp.2006.02.001

Answer (score 2):

On [this website](https://www.oecd.org/skills/piaac/Annex-A-Measures-of-the-big-five-dimensions.pdf) the scoring of the [Big 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) is explained a bit better I think. They refer to the original Big 5 paper that you've linked.

From what I understand there are 10 questions, and each of the 5 character traits is represented by 2 questions. One question is counted as is, while the other question in the pair is reversed-scored to describe the character trait. The reverse scoring of one of the answer pairs is necessary because that question is asked in an opposite approach.

There are 5 traits (the Big 5):

**Extraversion**: 1R, 6
**Agreeableness**: 2, 7R
**Conscientiousness**: 3R, 8
**Neuroticism**: 4R, 9
**Openness to experience**: 5R; 10

So extraversion is scored using the reverse score of question 1 and the score of question 6. Note that the question 6 (asking to rate 'extravertness') is opposite to question 1 ('introvertness').

Likewise, agreeableness is scored using the score of question 2 and the reverse score of question 7.
*etctera*.

Hope this helps.